# What does the Hammock.dll do?

Tags: nuget, couchbase, hammock

I referenced the **Couchbase** assembly using **NuGET** in my project and it has a dependency on **Hammock.dll**. What does this assembly do? And is it really needed? In simple unit tests, my application works fine without the `Hammock.dll` being present. But I don't want any surprises when I move this app to production.

Answer (score 1):

I would say [couchbase] [still needs it](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/master/src/Couchbase/HammockHttpClient.cs), given there is a `HammockHttpclient`.

To answer the original question:

> [Hammock](http://nuget.org/packages/Hammock) is an HTTP API library for .NET that greatly simplifies consuming and wrapping RESTful services.

This can easily be reasearched by going to the [CouchbaseNetClient](http://nuget.org/packages/CouchbaseNetClient) page and under *Dependancies* clicking Hammock. You can also go to the [Couchbase Project](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client) and browse through the source to view if/where the library is still being used (as I have linked in the first sentence).